# not able to add Google Admob

Tags: android, admob

I wrote code for Admob. This is my layout.xml file code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutHomeParent"
tools:context=".Home" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutHomeTopBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Home"
        style="@style/screen_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewHomeSettings"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/set_settings"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayoutHomeTopBar"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewHome"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="#BDBDBD"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view1" >
</ListView>

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    app:adSize="BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="a1512f50d8c3692"
    app:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    app:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>
```

Output:

[image: Screen shot]

I want the bar that is on the top(yes that black bar), on the bottom of the screen. I also wrote for it but it showed the output as the above image.

Also i dont understand that which one is the admob banner, the top one or the bottom one ?? Can anyone please explain the difference these two bars. Actually i am new to this. This is the first time i've code for admob. Please help me to learn on this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the ADK update has messed-up with your project's build-path. Try removing the admob JAR and add it again to your `libs` folder, add it to your `Build Path` and do a Clean Project.

EDIT following poster's comment about not having a libs folder:

You should try this:

1. Remove all references to the AdMob JAR in your project -> your code should not build without error anymore
2. Create a `libs` folder at the root of your project.
3. Copy the AdMob JAR into the libs folder
4. Make sure this AdMob JAR is in your Build Path (this will allow your code to build wihtout error)
   (If still not running OK) Right click your project > Android Tools > Fix Project Properties